# How do I shorten up this overly long JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script that selects a class's  and adds a class of selected to it and remove it from all other 's with the similar class.  It all works perfectly, but I know that there has to be a better way to write this out, I just can't figure it out.. Does it involve something like this?

```
$('.adv-option-set a, .adv-option-set2 a, .adv-option-set3 a, .adv-option-set4 a, .adv-option-set5 a, .adv-option-set6 a, .adv-option-set7 a').click(function()
{
    // if clicked item is selected then do nothing
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){}

    // otherwise deselect all and select just this one
    else
    {
        $('.adv-option-set a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }

    {
        $('.adv-option-set2 a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }

    {
        $('.adv-option-set3 a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

So here is the code that I currently have and is working:

```
$('.adv-option-set a').click(function()
{
    // if clicked item is selected then do nothing
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){}

    // otherwise deselect all and select just this one
    else
    {
        $('.adv-option-set a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});

$('.adv-option-set2 a').click(function()
{
    // if clicked item is selected then do nothing
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){}

    // otherwise deselect all and select just this one
    else
    {
        $('.adv-option-set2 a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});

$('.adv-option-set3 a').click(function()
{
    // if clicked item is selected then do nothing
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){}

    // otherwise deselect all and select just this one
    else
    {
        $('.adv-option-set3 a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Etc. up until '.adv-option-set7 a'

EDITED to show the DOM:

```
      <article id="filter">
        <ul id="filter-nav" class="option-set">
          <li>Filter: </li>
          <li><a data-categories="*" data-subid="all" class="selected">All</a></li>
          <li><a data-categories="tubs-and-showers" data-subid="tubs-and-showers">Tubs &amp; Showers</a></li>
          <li><a data-categories="countertops" data-subid="countertops">Countertops</a></li>
          <li><a data-categories="faucets" data-subid="faucets"><s>Faucets</s></a></li>
          <li><a data-categories="cabinetry" data-subid="cabinetry"><s>Cabinetry</s></a></li>
          <li><a data-categories="flooring" data-subid="flooring"><s>Flooring</s></a></li>
          <li><a data-categories="toilets" data-subid="toilets"><s>Toilets</s></a></li>
          <li><a data-categories="accessories" data-subid="accessories"><s>Accessories</s></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="advfilter" class="advfilter filter-nav hidden">
          <ul id="tubs-and-showers" class="adv-option-set1">
            <li><span class="small">ADV</span> Filter: </li>
            <li><a data-categories="modular">Modular</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="custom">Custom</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="countertops" class="adv-option-set2">
            <li><span class="small">ADV</span> Filter: </li>
            <li><a data-categories="marble">Marble</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="solid-surface">Solid Surface</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="laminate"><s>Laminate</s></a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="granite"><s>Granite</s></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="faucets" class="adv-option-set3">
            <li><span class="small">ADV</span> Filter: </li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="cabinetry" class="adv-option-set4">
            <li><span class="small">ADV</span> Filter: </li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="flooring" class="adv-option-set5">
            <li><span class="small">ADV</span> Filter: </li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="toilets" class="adv-option-set6">
            <li><span class="small">ADV</span> Filter: </li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="accessories" class="adv-option-set7">
            <li><span class="small">ADV</span> Filter: </li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a data-categories="">Coming Soon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>
```

FINAL EDIT: This is the other part of the JS code that I have, it seems that your answers actually take this part into effect aswell though:

```
    $("#advfilter ul").hide();
    $('.option-set a').on('click', function() {
        $("#advfilter ul").hide();
        $("#advfilter").removeClass('hidden');
        $("#" + $(this).attr('data-subid')).show();
        /*location.href='#filter'*/
    });

    $('.option-set a').click(function()
    {
        // if clicked item is selected then deselect it
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
        {
           $('.adv-option-set1 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set2 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set3 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set4 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set5 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set6 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set7 a').removeClass('selected');
        }

        // otherwise deselect all and select just this one
        else
        {
           $('.option-set a').removeClass('selected');
           $(this).addClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set1 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set2 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set3 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set4 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set5 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set6 a').removeClass('selected');
           $('.adv-option-set7 a').removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you show us the DOM, please?

Comment: Why do you have different classnames. Why not have the SAME class name but different IDs?

Comment: Look at my updated answer. It's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Option #1 would be a simple loop:

```
for (var i=1; i<=7; i++) (function(){
    var links = $('.adv-option-set'+i+' a');
    links.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('selected')) { // could be left out
            links.removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');
        }
    });
})();
```

Note that this code does not remove any classes, as your comment (not the code) to `.adv-option-set3` ("*…then deselect it*") implies, it "*do[es] nothing*" when the item is already selected. If you want to enable removing the class, you might want to use this snippet in the handler:

```
if ($(this).toggleClass('selected').hasClass('selected'))
    links.not(this).removeClass('selected');
```

Option #2 would be to set up the same event handler for all links (better: use delegated events) and get the sibling links where the class should be removed dynamically. The code for this depends on your DOM setup.

---

OK, now that I see your dom I have some additional points.

- The classes are really useless. You seem to use the to identify one element - which is already unique identified by its `id`. Use (the same) `class="adv-option-set"` on all of them to *classify* them.

  The code for option #2 - both elegant and efficient - would then look like this:

```
$("#advfilter").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('selected')
      .closest(".adv-option-set").find("a").not(this).removeClass('selected');
});
// or, little better but tightier bound to the DOM:
$("#advfilter").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('selected')
      .parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass('selected');
});
```

- I'm not sure, but you should really take a look at traditional radio buttons to build your form with. After that is done, you might enhance it with some JavaScript.

Comment: Is this not what [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) was meant to do?

Comment: No, the code moves the class to the clicked element, it does not toggle it.

Comment: Thank you, this code worked perfectly. @Cranio's code worked perfectly as-well though, since his has less lines of code, does it mean that his method is better? or is yours for some reason or what?  I'm not entirely sure how to know which one to use /:  Thanks! :)

Comment: No, it does different things (removes the selection from all groups), ans less efficient as well.

Comment: I'm confused, if they do different things, why do both of them react identically? You can see what I'm using the code for in action [HERE](http://remodeling-buffalo.com/bathroom/) to get an idea of what it looks like, so yours is more efficient then even though it's more lines of code?  I'm assuming his works for any number of adv-options while yours has to be given a max number.  Other than that, I don't see it acting any differently?  and if his removes the selection from all groups, that doesn't seem to matter as they are hidden unless their selected, should I just use yours?Thanks again :)

Comment: No, his code removes the selection from all filters. With mine you can select custom tubs, go to countertops and select marble ones, and still have the custom filter selected when going back to tubs.

Comment: Ohh okay, this makes sense.  I just added the second part of my JS code (the remaining bit that affects the entire code, probably should have put that originally, but i thought it would overwhelm things.  I guess I could have it so the filter remains set even when you click off to a separate item, but the hide function gets reset, so it's like the ADV filter also has to be unselected to mirror the action.  Thanks again, I'm learning A LOT from this, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: EDIT: I used your method, and removed the classes, but now the bottom script that I had has to be fixed aswell as it pertained to the individual classes.  I just added the JS to the initial post.  If you could help me with that final part then everything should be fixed and I am ecstatic right now, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14816/discussion-between-flip4life-and-bergi)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('[class^=adv-option-set] a').click(
    function()
    {
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       $('[class^=adv-option-set] a').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly as-well.  Is this a better way of doing it than @Bergi's method?  Both work the same, yours seems to be less code though, so is it better?

Comment: This might need to go up an element in the tree, i think.  Or use `$(this).siblings()`.  Judging by the original code, it looks like only the links in the current set should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Flip4Life It depends. With the first Bergi's code you can specify exactly how many classes you have to select/unselect (f. ex. seven up till to adv-option-set7), my code works for a generic number. Having to specify a precise number is usually useless for purposes like yours (you may wish to add "selectable" links at will)

Comment: @cHao I don't understand, my code works indeed on the links and makes them mutually exclusive. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. But first of all, the code doesn't make sense. You said "otherwise deselect all and select just this one", but really you're deselecting THIS one and then re-selecting it. So first off, give a common class name to all of them. Then, using jQuery, you can do:

```
$(".commonClassName").each(function(index, item){
    item.click(function(){
        $(".commonClassName").removeClass('selected');  //no matter what, deselect all of them
        if(!item.hasClass('selected'))
        {
            item.addClass('selected');  //then select this one if it isn't already
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan no, not really. Toggle would work pretty well if he wanted to toggle the class *every* time the button is clicked, but if the button is already selected, he wants to keep it the same. So you *could* use toggle, but it'd actually make the solution more complicated

Comment: yeah, exactly.. You can see the script in action [HERE](http://remodeling-buffalo.com/bathroom/) and it will probably make sense as to why I did it this way.  Thanks for the suggestion though, @Bergi's code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use starts with in jQuery as below:

```
$('div[class^="adv-option-set"] a').click(function()
{

   // if clicked item is selected then do nothing
   if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
   {
   }else
   {
     $('div[class^="adv-option-set"] a').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
   }

}
```

I hope this would help, this is called attribute start with selectors below is reference link for you to have look at:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

this is i think shortest code, I am hopping

Thanks Ankur

Comment: Shouldn't the class be without starting dot?

Comment: This method is similar to Cranio's and his worked perfectly.  Thanks so much for this, without the . infront of the classname, I assume it works identical to his.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Yah, sorry I didn't test it I just wrote it straight as general so that he can get overall idea. I'll update that thanks for letting me know.